# How do I connect to the host machine's Postgres from Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to connect to Postgres on my host machine from docker to deploy ODKAggregate. Here is my docker file:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.16-jre8-alpine
MAINTAINER Brian Otieno "obrienotieno@icloud.com" 
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

How do I tweak the Dockerfile to listen to Postgres on the host?

Answer (score 0):

Change `listen_address` on to `*` from `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf`

This basically allows any IP to connect to your Postgres, the default will be localhost

`sudo nano /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf`

And change like this
`listen_addresses = '*'`

And change your project settings to connect with your host system Postgres port